# How get data from fixture globally?

Tags: python, pytest

How to get data that is stored in a variable in a test, but globally?
Here my conftest.py, fixture called target_env, it takes data from the json file depending on the stand
[image]
This is test in which I want to apply data from a fixture, outside test, in @qase.description( )
[image]

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Find solution with pytest global variable and pytest hooks:

```py
pytest.env_data = None
def pytest_configure(config):
    config_path = config.getoption('--env')
    with open(config_path) as config_file:
        pytest.env_data = json.load(config_file)
    return pytest.env_data
```